# Внешний ip для сервера tcp

Tags: сервер, ip, tcp

Есть простой tcp сервер. Как задать ему внешний ip, чтобы можно было подключиться к нему с другого компа? И как собственно подключаться к нему? telnet "ip" "port"

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"

void client(int sock);
char *filesInDir();

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int accepted_socket;
    int listen_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (-1 == listen_socket)
    {
    perror("Socket can't created!");
    exit(1);
    }
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ADDRESS);
    if (-1 == bind(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)))
    {
    perror("Socket can't bind!");
    exit(1);
    }

    if (-1 == listen(listen_socket, 10))
    {
    perror("Socket can't listen!");
    exit(1);
    }

    for (;;) {
    accepted_socket = accept(listen_socket, 0, 0);
    if (-1 == accepted_socket) {
        perror("Socket can't accept!");
        exit(1);
    }
    client(accepted_socket);
    }
}

void client(int sock)
{
    while (1) {
    size_t name_len, cmd_len;
    char msg[] = ">> Write your command: ";
    char name_buf[256];
    char cmd_buf[256];
    write(sock, msg, sizeof(msg));
    name_len = read(sock, name_buf, sizeof(name_buf));
    if (-1 == name_len) {
        perror("Read error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (name_len > 0 &&
           ('\n' == name_buf[name_len] - 1 ||
            '\r' == name_buf[name_len] - 1)) {
        name_len--;
    }
    name_buf[name_len] = 0;
    if (!strcmp(name_buf, "cmd\r\n")) {
        FILE *file;
        char file_buf[1024];
        char cmd_msg[] = ">> Write your CMD command: ";
        while (1) {
            write(sock, cmd_msg, sizeof(cmd_msg));
            cmd_len = read(sock, cmd_buf, sizeof(cmd_buf));
            if (-1 == cmd_len) {
                perror("Read error!");
                exit(1);
            }
            while (cmd_len > 0 &&
                   ('\n' == cmd_buf[cmd_len] - 1 ||
                    '\r' == cmd_buf[cmd_len] - 1)) {
                cmd_len--;
            }
            cmd_buf[cmd_len] = 0;
            cmd_buf[strlen(cmd_buf) - 2] = 0;
            if (!strcmp(cmd_buf, "exit")){
                break;
            }
            system(cmd_buf);
        }
    }

    else if (!strcmp(name_buf, "exit\r\n"))
    {
        break;
    }
    printf(">> USER SEND COMMAND: %s", name_buf);
    printf(">> USER SEND CMD COMMAND: %s\n", cmd_buf);
    }
    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: вместо 127.0.0.1 укажите этот самый ip или 0.0.0.0, что будет означать любые ip этого компа

Comment: если указать 127.0.0.1, то пишет что этот адрес не может быть присвоен. А если указать 0.0.0.0 то по какому ip подключаться?

Comment: по тому который у вашего компа. и смотря откуда подключаться. если из локальной сети - то смотрите какой адрес операционная система назначила сетевухе (или может вы сами его в настройках указывали), а если из интернета, убедитесь, что у вас реальный IP или проброшены порты, если вы за NAT и можете его узнать через какой нибудь внешний сервис вроде internet.yandex.ru

Comment: Можно немножко понятнее, пожалуйста. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы я мог подключиться к серверу с другого компа.

Comment: понятнее невозможно, потому что это зависит от вашей операционной системы и ее версии. ваш вопрос стоило бы сформулировать как "как узнать свой ip адрес" и в такой формулировке google на него отлично ответит, особенно если к нему приписать еще свою ОС

Comment: Ну я ведь не настолько тупой, чтобы не попробовать подключаться по своему внешнему ip. Ну не работает оно так.

Comment: А вы уверены, что вы не за NAT и ваш провайдер не запретил все входящие соединения к вам ? и откуда именно вы пытаетесь обращаться, откуда то издалека или с другого компа в пределах своей локальной сети (в пределах локальной сети внешний ip может не работать, т.к. на компе физически его нет, а стоит какой нибудь локальный, который стоит посмотреть ipconfig/ifconfig/...)

Comment: Спасибо, с локалкой разобрался.